# Initializing google maps display

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, safari

I am creating a web app that uses the Google Maps API to display a map. When I reload the page it does not initialize the map where my coordinates tell it to and is "fuzzy". Once I zoom out using the toolbar on the left and zoom back in everything is fine. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map_canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50%;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.3584170693, -71.065063476),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

  var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
  bikeLayer.setMap(map);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.346872819794896, -71.06643676757812),
      map: map,
      title: 'REPORT'
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.363363955820496, -71.08978271484375),
      map: map,
      title: 'REPORT'
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 90%; height: 300%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your inline height conflicts with your css height, btw.

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox. Are you having issues in a particular browser? Please edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your markers are around (42.3, -71), Boston, but the map's center as written in the options, is missing a '4' and sending the initial location to Colombia at (2.3, -71).

About the fuzzyness, could it just be the bicycling layer taking a while to load? I am unable to reproduce this effect.

Comment: Yes! It was the problem with the initial location. Thank you! I forgot the '4'.